# How to calculate confidence interval on pivot table?

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval

I'd like to create a series of tables on the cheapest and most expensive streets around where I live, and wonder if someone could help with a query about confidence.

I've got a set of house transaction data that provides variables for the price of properties in a year, along with the street and area.

I've pivoted the data by area and street and calculated columns for the the median price and count of properties sold:

```
                                        price
                                median  count   std
district        street          
CANNOCK CHASE   ABBEY STREET    182500  3       23780.787063
                ABBOTS WALK     134000  1       NaN
```

While I could sort the results on median price and publish as is, I'm uncomfortable without listing some measure of how representative it really is so I can filter out outliers based on single properties (such as the second entry in this table).

I know this is trivial, but can someone give me a simple steer on how to proceed?

Answer (score -1):

I've had a dig around and found this post about data analysis with Pandas by Randy Olson.

http://www.randalolson.com/2012/08/06/statistical-analysis-made-easy-in-python/

That made the calculation of standard error of the mean and other stats straightforward.

However, it also the fact that I should have been considering the shape of the distribution instead of blindly calculating stats.

Comment: Calculating statistics has almost nothing to do with the question of "how representative" a sample might be.  If your question is really about "filtering out outliers based on single properties," just remove all lines with counts of 1.